# Duda de lectura de secuencias en Python

Tags: python

tengo un problema con mi programa en python, mi código me marca un error que no comprendo, lo que quiero hacer es dado un archivo txt (que es una secuencia de números) quiero dibujar el punto medio entre un punto y una esquina que esta dada por cada numero de la secuencia. Si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradeceré muchisimo, este es mi código:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sqrt, zeros
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import random, randint
def midpoint(p, q):
    return (0.5*(p[0] + q[0]), 0.5*(p[1] + q[1]))
# esquinas del cuadrado
esquina = [(0, 0), (0, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0)]
N = 10
x = zeros(N)
y = zeros(N)
#punto inicial
x[0] = 0.55
y[0] = 0.55
#llamar la lista, zip(a,b) hace correspondencia uno a uno 

for i in range(1, N):
    k = open('secuencia.txt','r') # esto me da la esquina 
    for k, esquina in zip(k, esquina):
    x[i], y[i] = midpoint( esquina[k], (x[i-1], y[i-1]) )
    k.close()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,7)) 
plt.scatter(x, y, color = "pink")
plt.show()
```

Me marca el siguiente error:

```
File "<ipython-input-5-e6ff7df343a5>", line 9
x[i], y[i] = midpoint( esquina[k], (x[i-1], y[i-1]) )
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: El problema es que la linea anterior a la del error (linea 8), hay un if que requiere que la siguiente este indentada. Te recomiendo leer el mensaje de error para la próxima XP

Comment: Gracias es que apenas estoy empezando con python jajaj

Answer (score 0):

Facil, después del for y los dos puntos necesitamos un línea indentada:

```
for k, esquina in zip(k, esquina):
    x[i], y[i] = midpoint( esquina[k], (x[i-1], y[i-1]) )
k.close()
```

Comment: Hola ya corregí lo que me indicaste pero ahora me aparece un error que dice "tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str" pero este error no me aparece en otro código similar que tengo

Comment: significa que estas usando una cadena de caracteres para indexar una lista que se hace por numeros, probablemente tenga que ver con la variable k